# программа крашится на scanf

Tags: c

Если я передаю scanf указатель на char, в который перед этим была записана строка то программа крашится на scanf.

```
char *a = "dfgdfg";
scanf("%s", a);
```

Comment: Записывать в строку, доступную только для чтения - сомнительная затея.

Comment: Что такое "указатель, в который перед этим была записана строка"? В указатель невозможно записать строку. В указатель можно записать только *адрес* чего-либо.

Comment: Хотел бы добавить, что если вы присваиваете строковый литерал указателю на `char`, то его следует делать константным, т.е. `const char *`. Строковые литералы всегда имеют доступ только для чтения и следует указывать это явно. Большинство компиляторов выдадют предупреждение, если указатель на строковый литерал не константный.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что когда ты присваиваешь строку к char* (при инициализации), ты получаешь строку, доступную только для чтения, а значит записать ты туда ничего не можешь :) Поэтому scanf и не работает.